# Как правильно написать Controller для блога на MVC PHP?

Tags: php, mvc

В качестве обучения пишу сайт на php с использованием mvc.
Упёрся в момент создания контроллера для записей блога.
Новость имеет url site/news/test_article
Уже реализовал функционал сохранения статьи из админки в БД, выполнил транслитерацию названия (заголовка), сохранил его в качестве алиаса.
Так вот как правильно описать контроллер для статьи?
По моей логике route считывает url, первая часть после доменного имени - это имя контроллера, вторая - это action. Но как быть, если использовать алиасы для url каждой записи?
Вот это написано для страницы новостей:

```
<?php
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $news = new News();
        $data = $news->get_news();
        $this->view->render("news/index", ["news"=>$data]);
    }
}
```

Route.php

```
<?php

class Route // Для разбора одрессной строки
{
    // Стартовая функция
    public static function start(){

        // Autoload models
        spl_autoload_register(function($models){
            if(file_exists("app/models/".$models.".php")){
                include_once "app/models/".$models.".php";
            }
        });

        $baseController = "Index"; // Дефолтный controller
        $baseAction = "index"; // Дефолтный action
        $routs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); // Принимаем url и разбиваем его по слешам

        // Проверка части url после первого слеша (отвечающего за controller)
        if(!empty($routs[1])){
            $baseController = $routs[1]; // Переопределение controller
        }

        // Преобразование строки в нижний регистр + Преобразование первого символа строки в верхний регистр + "Controller"
        $baseController = str_replace("-", "_", $baseController);
        $baseController = ucfirst(strtolower($baseController)) . "Controller";
        $controllerPath = "app/controllers/" . $baseController . ".php"; // Полный путь к controller

        // Проверка части url после второго слеша (отвечающего за action)
        if(!empty($routs[2])){
            $baseAction = $routs[2]; // Переопределение action
        }

        // Преобразование строки в нижний регистр
        $baseAction = str_replace("-", "_", $baseAction);
        $baseAction = strtolower($baseAction) . "Action";

        // Проверка наличия файла
        if(file_exists($controllerPath)){
            include_once $controllerPath;
        } else {
            self::error404();
        }

        // Создание объекта controller
        $controller = new $baseController;

        // Проверка существования метода
        if(method_exists($controller, $baseAction)){
            $controller->$baseAction();
        } else {
            self::error404();
        }

    }

    public static function error404(){
        $host = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/"; // Адрес сайта
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); // Заголовок
        header("Status 404 Not Found"); // Статус
        header("Location: " . $host . "error404"); // Редирект
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется тут много писать получится.... двумя-тремя строками не ограничится.... Я б просто посоветовал скачать `yii2` и посмотреть в их ядро... в классы `UrlManager` и `UrlRule` - как раз разобраться как они это делают. Чтоб применить это к себе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с ошибок

> По моей логике route считывает url,

Объект Router должен заниматься именно этим, только несколько глубже - не просто считывать урл а делать преобразование URL+POST+COOKIES+.. -> объект Request, так же роутер вычисляет наименование контроллера и экшна . При конструкции и вызове контроллера - в контроллер передаётся объект Request .

> Но как быть, если использовать алиасы для url каждой записи?

То есть как роутер выбирает контроллер и экшн? Обычно это делается по конфигу распознавания URL - который отдаётся роутеру. Пример из моего любимого фреймворка Zend2

```
[
'offers_default' => [//универсальный роут модуля Offers
                'type'    => '\Engine\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/offers/:controller[/:action]*',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => [
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Offers\Controller',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ],
                ],
                'priority' => -1000,
],
'home' => [//роут для главной страницы
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
          ]
]
```

Самостоятельное написание MVC полезно только для саморазвития. Можно подсмотреть - как это устроено во фреймворках.

**Непосредственно ответ на вопрос**:

Нужно сделать парсинг URL-а регулируемым кофигом, конфиг должен быть устроен таким образом, что можно сопоставить неким алгоритмом по нему URL => MCA (модуль контроллер экшн). Тогда можно будет любой адрес перенаправлять в желаемый контроллер. Гибкость конфига - отвечает за его объём, чтобы внести все желаемые URL-адреса: если конфигурирование гибкое, то оно ёмкое, читабельное и расширяемое.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развёрнутый ответ, буду разбираться.